# Working with custom attributes / directives in HTML + Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, vue.js

I've been going through `vue.js` and `angular.js` code, but cannot figure out how do they handle custom directives in html?

For example, let's say I have the following div:
`<div my-repeat="item in items"></div>`

To achieve something similar to what `vue.js` does, do I have to scan the whole document's DOM elements to find all the occurances of `my-` attribute prefix and then somehow try to figure out what the rest of its functionality does?

I have literally spent a few hours trying to figure this out, but with no luck. Any ideas / directions would be much appreciated please.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know for certain how Vue and Angular do it, but here's an example of how you could implement functionality specified in a custom attribute:

```js
var element = document.querySelector('[function-attribute]');
var fn = new Function(element.attributes['function-attribute'].value).bind(element);
fn();
```

```html
<div value-attribute='something' function-attribute="alert(this.attributes['value-attribute'].value);"></div>
```

Comment: But wouldn't that be invalid html? Also, I don't see how I could create / bind a functionality out of that..

Comment: @SuchMuchCode AFAIK it is invalid html, but is used nevertheless. I updated my code snippet with an idea about how to create functionality this way.